# How can I use face authentication to log in?

Tags: login, webcam, authentication

I got a new Dell laptop and I used to login into Windows using webcam authentication. Now I have removed Windows and installed Ubuntu but I could not find any application for face authentication. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a program called [pam-face-authentication](http://pam-face-authentication.org/), although it is not in the repositories, so you will have to install it by following the [instructions](http://pam-face-authentication.org/downloads.php) - there is a ppa.

The documentation site doesn't seem to work but you can try looking in `/usr/share/doc/pam-face-authentication` to find documentation once you have installed.

You should note that the security of alternative authentication methods such as fingerprint readers and face recognition is questionable, i.e. not as good as a strong password.

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks. I am using the laptop for home use and not for work so I am not much concerned about security. Just one question - Is it safe? it won't break my system, right?

Comment: It should be OK but with PPA packages there is always a risk. See the [warnings on this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/add-applications/C/adding-repos.html).